# How to check text contain alphabet and digit

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox that user enter a string into it.

```
 <td class ="auto-style2" > <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_PassportCode" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox></td>
```

and:

```
string code=TextBox_PassportCode.text;
```

I want to check if "code" contain `alphabet + digit` together. Eg,A1234 or 1234A Or fhg21564,
It is not important how many alphabet or how many digit user enter, but textbox should contain alphabet and digit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Regex to allow only alpha numeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133669/c-sharp-regex-to-allow-only-alpha-numeric)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing like below. Since you said the text could be either `A1234` or `1234A`; it not necessary that string starts with alphabet. In which case, you can check against regular expression `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` which will match combination of 1 or more alphabet + digits. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms228595.aspx) on how to use

```
string code=TextBox_PassportCode.text;
string pat = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+";

if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(code, pat, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
   System.Console.WriteLine("Match Found");
}
else
{
  System.Console.WriteLine("No Match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression for this.

See this answer.

[C# Regex to allow only alpha numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133669/c-sharp-regex-to-allow-only-alpha-numeric)

Comment: Thanks,But how must use ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$ ? in method ?

Comment: Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"); var isMatch = rg.IsMatch(code); if(isMatch){doCoolStuff();};

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Regex' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I added using  System.Web; but it didnt work.

Comment: add a using reference like "using System.Text.RegularExpressions" in the top of your class